# SQL Server: assigning string literals to a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do something like:

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL N'select * from Members where Name like @pat',
   N'@pat nvarchar(max)', @pat=Tom
```

My question is about the last parameter.

When the value to assign is a "simple" string, i.e. no spaces etc, I could use something like `@pat=Tom`, no quotes needed.

However, when the value to assign ends with the `%` character for example, it won't work, and I have to do something like `@pat=N'Tom%'`.

Is this how the syntax of assigning a string literal is defined?

Does it also mean that if my value contains the single quotation mark, I would have to escape it manually?

Comment: I'm really surprised `@pat=Tom` doesn't fail as MS docs says it should be `@param = 'value'` where `The value can be a Unicode constant or a Unicode variable` and  Tom is neither constant nor variable.

Comment: How on earth did it work http://rextester.com/UACGW14527 I would expect it throw invalid identifier error

Comment: Surprisingly, @pat=Tom works without single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that it works with no quotes.  This must be a peculiarity of `exec`.

Always include the single quotes:

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL N'select * from Members where Name like @pat',
   N'@pat nvarchar(max)', @pat='Tom';
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql):

> If the value of a parameter is an object name, **character string**, or
>   qualified by a database name or schema name, **the whole name must be
>   enclosed in single quotation marks**. If the value of a parameter is a
>   keyword, the keyword must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

I don't know why it would work without the single quotes.